# where is the visual studio user guide

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Does Visual Studio have a user guide, or any such document that provides the complete list of functionality of the application. Just to be clear, any document that details all of the functionality, eg like Resharpers online help at http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/

I have googled the above with not much success. (i have also tried F1 within VS itself)

I am not a beginner nor am I searching for the answer to a specific Visual Studio question; rather I just want to read thru all it has to offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a user guide as per Hans' answer it can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(MSDNSTART)&rd=true

Like any documentation for a complex piece of software it has its good areas and bad areas but, for the most part, gets you down the knowledge path.  One great feature is that the community can add content to the documentation to augment what is there or correct mistakes as needed.

Comment: This is good enough, Thanks. Not sure why Haans answer disappeared?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any user guide, but there are a few good books available specifically on visual studio (2008/2010). Just look around on the internet...